# Show $\sum_{d|n} d\mu(d) = ((-1)^{ω(n)}ϕ(n)s(n))/n$

Tags: number-theory, totient-function, mobius-function

I shall define some functions first. For $n$ being any positive integer,

$ω(n) =$ no. of distinct primes $p$ which divides $n$.

$\mu(n) = (-1)^{ω(n)}$ if $n$ is square-free; $= 0$ if not.

$s(n) =$ the largest square-free factor of $n = \prod_{p|n} p$.

How can we show that
$$\sum_{d|n} d\mu(d) = ((-1)^{ω(n)}ϕ(n)s(n))/n?$$

Many thanks.

Comment: Both side are multiplicatives functions of $n$. It is enough to show it for $n=p^k$. Equivalently, you can write them in the form $\prod_{p^k \| n} f(p^k)$ as Marko Riedel did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $p|n$ the primes dividing $n$ we get for the LHS

$$\prod_{p|n} (1+\mu(p)p) = \prod_{p|n} (1-p).$$

We get for the RHS

$$(-1)^{\omega(n)} \times n \times
\prod_{p|n} \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right) \times \prod_{p|n} p
\times \frac{1}{n}
\\ = (-1)^{\omega(n)}
\prod_{p|n} \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right) \times \prod_{p|n} p
\\ = (-1)^{\omega(n)}
\prod_{p|n} \left(p-1\right)
\\ = \prod_{p|n} \left(1-p\right).$$

This is the claim.

Comment: Can you explain more why ω(n) is odd?

Comment: It doesn't need to be. What we use here is $(-1)^{\omega(n)} = \prod_{p|n} (-1).$

Comment: Is this because ω(n) counts there are how many such p?